# How to visualize spin density isosurfaces?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp

What is the package used for visualization of spin density isosurfaces in VASP like the ones shown below? A simple example/tutorial would be very appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the packages [VASPKIT](https://vaspkit.com/tutorials.html#density-related) and [VESTA](https://jp-minerals.org/vesta/en/) to realize this. Here I just outline the whole flow to obtain spin-related density. I assume you are considering magnetic materials.

- Relax your structure in spin-polarized mode (`ISPIN=2`).
- Self-consistent calculation with your relaxed structure in the spin-polarized mode. Remember to output the `CHGCAR` file, which contains the information of charge density and also spin density.
- Use the VASPKIT to extract the data stored in `CHGCAR` file [vaspkit==> option 31]:

  - 311: output charge density: `CHARGE.vasp`
  - 312: output spin density: `SPIN.vasp`
  - 313: output spin-up and spin-down separately: `SPIN_UP.vasp` and `SPIN_DW.vasp`
- Visualize these output files `XXX.vasp` with `VESTA`.

Comment: What is the best/meaningful value of isosurface level to take ? or I can take whatever I want ?

Comment: @ChiKou Yes, you can set it as you want! But always use the same values if you want to do some comparisons.

Comment: Can I use even smaller values like 0.0001ang ?

Comment: You can. But you must say what the value is in the caption of your figure.